# Pandas - Datatype Object - .loc not working on numbers

Tags: python, excel, pandas

so I have a very simple pandas script that I use to replace values in excel with other values. There is one colum (Fm) that does not work when I am trying to replace the numerical values. Column Fm dtype is object. But it just will not work when I try to replace the 350 value, (Commented in my code the line) but everything else works. I can't attached a file to stackoverflow and do not feel comfortable creating a link because I am on work machine. Has anyone seen an issue of this nature?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel("2.27.xlsm", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", dtype=object)
data.loc[data.F == 'DBD', 'F'] = 'BFD'
data.loc[data.Fm == '350', 'Fm'] = 'test' # this line does not work
data.loc[data.Fm == 'B25', 'F'] = 'BFD'
data.loc[data.Fm == 'B50', 'F'] = 'BFD'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

Name: Fm, Length: 1521, dtype: object
```

**-- Sorry I have  second Part to this Question starting below here as lines 7-8 appear to negate 1-6?-----**

Hi, I have an example script below that I run on an excel file. Essentially **after** **line 6** I want to filter out rows that contain BFD and SFD in Column F( I know just assigned these values in the code above, and more of those values also existed in different rows prior to the script). After this is filtered just apply the logic in lines 7-8 to the data frame. So essentially ya use pandas to filter out rows by cell value in column then apply logic to what did not get filtered out and then just unfiltered everything ( as if you were to clear filters in excel) and have my data frame be ready to go

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel("2.27.xlsm", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", dtype=object)
data.loc[data.F == 'DBD', 'F'] = 'BFD'
data.loc[data.F == 'DUB', 'F'] = 'BFD'
data.loc[data.F == 'DCD', 'F'] = 'SFD'
#Now I want to apply this logic and filter out any rows that have values of BFD or SF in column F and then apply to logic below (to not overwrite any work done above)
data.loc[data.Fm == 'B25', 'F'] = 'BFD'
data.loc[data.Fm == 'B50', 'F'] = 'BFD'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Try using `data.loc[data.Fm.astype(str) == '350', 'Fm'] = 'test'`

Comment: @Chris your a legend it worked!

Comment: @Chris if you have a change, I updated a second part to my question, because essentially the second part of my code negates the first part.

Comment: It is not recommended to change question that already has an accepted answer. Please post a new question.

Comment: Apologies @Chris

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about :)

Comment: @Chris https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931435/pandas-approach-to-excel-filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation doing a merge, I think what might happen is that while the column is an object, each cell is considered separately when doing comparisons. 
Meaning that if you want to or have mixed data types in your columns, you want to set that column (in this case) to strings before doing the comparisons.

Try:

```
dafa.loc[:,'Fm'] = data.Fm.astype(str)
```

This will convert all your cells to strings (e.g. 350 will be '350')

Then:

```
data[data.Fm == '350', 'Fm'] = 'test'
```

FYI: I do not think you need the .loc in this cas.

Comment: thank you for input, I used Chris's code and it worked. 
 data.loc[data.Fm.astype(str) == '350', 'Fm'] = 'test'

Comment: Glad that you got your answer. Is technically the same, the difference is that you need to apply his for ecery value, mine is doing it as a whole.

Comment: Glad that you got your answer. Is technically the same, the difference is that you need to apply his for ecery value, mine is doing it as a whole.

Comment: if you have another moment how would I do the equivalent to filter out rows that have  values lets say in Column F that are now BFD? So I can apply the next lines of logic to values that have note been filtered out>

Comment: @pes04. I think the best way to deal with the second question is to make it a new question. I will think about an answer but I think you want to do data[data.F.isin(data.BFD.unique()] Let me know if this works and if not, make a new question. And add the link here.