# Pandas approach to Excel Filter

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an example script below that I run on an excel file. Essentially **after** **line 6** I want to filter out rows that contain BFD and SFD in Column F( I know just assigned these values in the code above, and more of those values also existed in different rows prior to the script). After this is filtered just apply the logic in lines 7-8 to the data frame. So essentially ya use pandas to filter out rows by cell value in column then apply logic to what did not get filtered out and then just unfiltered everything ( as if you were to clear filters in excel) and have my data frame be ready to go

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel("2.27.xlsm", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", dtype=object)
data.loc[data.F == 'DBD', 'F'] = 'BFD'
data.loc[data.F == 'DUB', 'F'] = 'BFD'
data.loc[data.F == 'DCD', 'F'] = 'SFD'
#Now I want to apply this logic and filter out any rows that have values of BFD or SF in column F and then apply to logic below (to not overwrite any work done above)
data.loc[data.Fm == 'B25', 'F'] = 'BFD'
data.loc[data.Fm == 'B50', 'F'] = 'BFD'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, as there's no data given, but this should do the trick for you:

```
filtered = [d for d in data if d['F'] == 'BFD' or d['F'] == 'SF'] 
# now proceed with your work
```

Comment: so you made a new dataframe, how do I put that back into the data dataframe so it combines together as it was prior ?

Comment: it throws an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Add a [sample call](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) on your dataframe and edit in into your question; I'd be happy to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert your data dataframe into a dataframe containing ONLY rows were column F has BDF or SDF

```
data = data[data.F.str.contains(r'^BFD$|^SFD$', case = False, na=False)]
```

Comment: how would do you convert it back. Like the equivalent to unfilter. Also I would want to filter out bdf and sdf not filter for

Comment: If you want to keep the 'other' rows, I suggest you make two new dataframes, one using the filter as above (let call is data1) and a second one added == False after the last ) in the script above (this is all but the filtered columns let's call it data2) once you are done, do data3 = pd.concat([data1, data2],0).

Comment: view my answer and lmk what you think

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for all the help, this is what I ended up doing. Please poke holes if you think this does not equate to an excel filter of filtering for items that start with UN making adjustments then clearing filters.

```
ta =  data[~data.Format.str.contains(r'UN', case = False, na=False, regex = False)] # trying regex
da = data[data.Format.str.contains(r'UN', case = False, na=False, regex = False)] # trying regex


final = pd.concat([ta, da],0) # now append seperate dataframes
```

Comment: so you got it! Great. FYI, the r before the pattern is for regex, which then you turn off. Just so you know. What mattars isnif it works for you.

Comment: @Jorge what do you mean by "Which then you turn off" and "isnif"

Comment: you have "r'UN'" meaning you are passing a regex pattern, then you set regex = False (turn it off). Hey if you like my answer do not forget to vote for it.